# I'm trying to get a int list in a while loop to store user input in c#

Tags: c#, while-loop, user-input

I got an assignment where I'm supposed collect the student number, name and surname and the test scores of a student and calculate the average of the student, then print that information to the console window. Now I'm struggling to create a while loop that will accept user input into the list (because the user will decide how many scores to input). Please note that I am a first year student and new to programming.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StudentRecord
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.Write("Enter your name and surname: ");
        string NameSurname = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter  your student number:");

        string StudentNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        if (StudentNumber.Length > 8)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exceeded digits entered");

            StudentNumber = Console.ReadLine();

        }
        else if (StudentNumber.Length < 8)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Insufficient digits entered");

            StudentNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        if (StudentNumber.All(char.IsDigit) == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + NameSurname + "Studentnumber: " + StudentNumber);


        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("has a non digit char");
        }


        List<int> Scores = new List<int>();


        while (true) {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a test score: ");
            Scores = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            break;
            };
   }
   }
   }
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you want us to solve. You have an infinite `while` loop from which you `break` out immediately after trying to assign a single `int` value to a `List<int>` (multiple `int` values) - variable. So there are multiple issues: You don't have a exit condition in your loop, you try to assign a value to a list of values (you probably want to use [`.Add`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add)). Also another problem I see is that you only catch wrong StudenNumbers once, the second time an invalid one will get accepted.

Comment: **[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)** you also might (ought) be interested in **[How to use the awesome, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

This may be the console app that you are looking for.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    struct Student
    {
        string number;
        string fullName; // both name and surname separated with space
        int score;

        public Student(string new_number, string new_fullName, int new_score)
        {
            number   = new_number;
            fullName = new_fullName;
            score    = new_score; 
        }

        public string toString()
        {
            return "Hello " + fullName + ", Studentnumber: " + number + " with Score: " + score.ToString();
        }

        public int getScore()
        {
            return score;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        private static List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

        private static void addNewStudent(Student student)
        {
            students.Add(student);
        }

        private static string getStudentNumber()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter your student number:");
            string studentNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            if (studentNumber.Length <= 8 && int.TryParse(studentNumber, out int n) == true)
            {
                return studentNumber;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insufficient digits entered");
                return getStudentNumber();
            }
        }

        private static string getStudentFullName()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter your name and surname: ");
            string fullName = Console.ReadLine();
            if(fullName.Contains(" "))
            {
                return fullName;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must enter both name and surname");
                return getStudentFullName();
            }

        }

        private static int getStudentScore()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a test score: ");
            try
            {
                int score = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                return score;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Score must be integer");
                return getStudentScore();
            }
        }
        static void getStudentInformation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Get new student information");
            string number = getStudentNumber();
            string fullName = getStudentFullName();
            int score = getStudentScore();
            Student newStudent = new Student(number, fullName, score);
            addNewStudent(newStudent);
            Console.WriteLine(newStudent.toString());


        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter A to Add new student, G to Get students list info and average score: ");
                string res = Console.ReadLine();
                if(res == "A")
                {
                    getStudentInformation();
                }
                else if (res == "G")
                {
                    if(students.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Student Number in the List: 0");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int scoreSum = 0;
                        foreach(Student student in students)
                        {
                            scoreSum += student.getScore();
                        }

                        float averageScore = scoreSum / students.Count;
                        Console.WriteLine("Average score is: " + averageScore.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have to type A or G");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Output from my machine:

```
Enter A to Add new student, G to Get students list info and average score: asfsfnf
You have to type A or G
Enter A to Add new student, G to Get students list info and average score: A
Get new student information
Enter your student number:112
Enter your name and surname: bill gate
Enter a test score: 100
Hello bill gate, Studentnumber: 112 with Score: 100
Enter A to Add new student, G to Get students list info and average score: A
Get new student information
Enter your student number:steve job
Insufficient digits entered
Enter your student number:130
Enter your name and surname: steve job
Enter a test score: 0
Hello steve job, Studentnumber: 130 with Score: 0
Enter A to Add new student, G to Get students list info and average score: G
Average score is: 50
Enter A to Add new student, G to Get students list info and average score:
```